# how to keep yum from updating a file I changed?

Tags: centos, yum, init.d, etc

I'm running CentOS 6.8, I had changed `/etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail` (something I couldn't do in `/etc/sysconfig/sendmail`) but yum overwrote the file when updating sendmail.  Is there a way to configure yum not to update certain files, and instead warn me of the change (and stash the new version somewhere, so I can merge my changes with the updates)?

Comment: You could always copy the script to `/etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail-custom` and start that service instead. Yum will update `/etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail` but not the copied version.

Comment: Since `/etc/sysconfig/sendmail` is probably sourced (with `.`) early on before any args are parsed you could add `exec /...mysendmail "$@"` to it and so run your overriding script.

Answer (score 3):

You really can't.  `yum` (or more strictly `rpm`) depends on the `%config` inside the RPM to decide that a file is a configuration file, i.e. a file marked with `%config(noreplace)` will be saved as `.rpmnew` when an updated file happens to be in the newer RPM.

You have two options:

- Download the RPM (not update with you) and repackage it with `%config(noreplace)` for `/etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail` and then install with yum.
- Download the RPM and use `rpm --excludepath` to install the package.  I like this option more, it is hacky but not as hacky as editing the RPM everytime it gets updated.  See below:

First exclude `sendmail` from being updated with `yum update`, in `/etc/yum.conf` place

```
exclude=sendmail*
```

This will make `yum` never updated the `sendmail` package but it will still list it with `yum check-update` so you will know a new sendmail RPM is available.  You can then download it with:

```
yum install -downloadonly --installroot=. sendmail-<version>
```

Then use `rpm` with `--excludepath` to not update the file in `/etc/rc.d`:

```
rpm --excludepath /etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail sendmail-<version>.rpm
```

Reference on the `%config`:

- [John Warbrick on %config](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm%5Fconfig.html)

Comment: You probably don't want to stop getting software updates for sendmail.  Turning off yum updates will make your system less secure.  It'd probably be better to just manage your own service file while leaving the existing RPM intact, as described in the comments.

Comment: @jsbillings - I guess you're right if OP uses something like `yum-cron`.  Otherwise he can just script the things together `yum update && yum check-update | grep sendmail && yum install --downloadonly ... && rpm --excludepath <sendmail>` (not tested).  And it will pick the update.

Comment: Uhmm, when you exclude sendmail from being updated via yum, why fiddle with `rpm --excludepath` when sendmail will not be updated anymore?

Comment: @doktor5000 - Ekhm... because you want sendmail to receive security updates?  `yum` is a system tool that takes RPMs as they are, whilst using `rpm` you can fiddle with the installation (don't ask me why it was designed that way, it just was).  Therefore, if you want to fiddle with the sendmail updates you need to (1) prevent yum from updating it and overwriting files (2) use yum to download the update but not install/update it (3) use rpm to install it the way you want it installed.

Comment: @grochmal Nope, sorry that approach is much to messy if you still want to be able to receive normal updates. I'd go another approach, don't disable exclude anything in yum config and don't fiddle with weird rpm options. Put the changes that need to be applied to `/etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail` in a small scriptlet, then put that in your own empty rpm in a `%triggerin` section which triggers on sendmail rpm updates, as explained in http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/triggers.html and then you can receive updates, and the changes to sendmail config will be redone each time.

Comment: @doktor5000 - Heh, I kind of like your approach.  I never used `%triggerin` but now I'm curious.  You should really add that as an alternative answer, I'll like to read it.

Comment: Well, as OP hasn't replied yet or commented on any of the easier proposals, I don't see much point in that, and I've already provided basically all relevant information - IMHO it's just overkill for the issue described here. Check the link above on %triggers or maybe http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm2/#triggers and use them yourself, it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the file immutable (`chattr +i /etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail`). Any (automatic) update of the package would then fail, which would make you aware of the situation; then simply remove the immutable flag, perform the update, redo your modification of the file, and set it immutable again.